# Iphone NSPredicate how to do an INNER JOIN?

Tags: iphone, core-data, join, nspredicate

I have been looking thru the documentation and some other posts in this site, but I simply cannot understand how to work this out, which is actually very simple in SQL.

Basically I have 2 entities Instruments and Deals. And the "Deals" use an "Instrument" to perform a desired operation. Now I want to list Deals attributes and the Instrument attributes that were used for this deal. So in SQL i would do:

SELECT *
FROM Instruments
INNER JOIN Deals
ON Instruments.ID = Deals.InstrumentID

How would I accomplish this with an NSPredicate?. Any help will be greatly apreciated. Thank you.

-Oscar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you should do what you can to get out of the SQL mindset. Core Data **is not** an ORM. It is an object graph management framework that *just happens* to use SQLite as one possible persistence backend. Although you can view the SQL it uses via environment variables (for debugging), the SQL is a private implementation detail. Core Data could have been implemented without any SQL at all.

So, try not to think in terms of db tables. You have a collection of `Deal` isntances. You want their properties? Use [Key-value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to get the properties of those instances and the related `Instrument` instances. Assuming you have an `NSSet` instance of `Deals`, called `deals`:

```
[deals valueForKey:@"dealProperty"];
```

will give you an `NSSet` of the values of `dealProperty` from each `Deal` instance. If you want to get multiple properties at once, you can use `-[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:]`. You can only get keys "one level deep" using this method, so only, e.g. 'dealProperty1', 'dealProperty2'  but not 'dealRelation.relationProperty' or 'dealRelation.@count'.

To get "nested" properties, just use a key path:

```
[deals valueForKeyPath:@"instrument.instrumentProperty"];
```

will give you a set of the values of the `instrumentProperty` of the `Instrument` instance associated with each `Deal` instance, assuming `instrument` is a one-to-one relationship from `Deal` to `Instrument`. If the relationship is one-to-many, you will get a set of sets of `instrumentProperty` values.

You can always do this more explicitly (obviously this code doesn't do any thing and isn't even syntactically correct since I've omitted semicolons etc., but it shows the outline):

```
for(Deal *deal in deals) {
  //use attribute access to get properties of deal and associated instrument
  deal.dealProperty
  deal.instrument.instrumentProperty //for one-to-one

  for(Instrument *instrument in deal.instruments) { //for one-to-many instruments
    instrument.instrumentProperty;
  }
}
```

using enumeration of the appropriate collections.