# Using NSPredicate and Joins

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have 2 tables: Users and Comments like so:

```
Users
user_id (PK)
name

Comments
comment_id (PK)
user_id
comment
```

I want to get a list of all users and their comments.

How is this done using `NSPredicate`?

Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question, but wouldn't it be simpler to have a `comments` relationship on the `User` entity, so that you could simply fetch all users (or all users with at least one comment), and then get the comments for a given user as `user.comments`?  Or are you not using Core Data for this?

Comment: its not about NSPredicate. If you are using SQLite, you just need a query

Comment: I agree with @BhanuPriya. The question needs to be more specific. Are you using CoreData or just need a SQL query? NSPredicate is not for general SQL queries.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understood your question, you are using core-data.

First of all, you have to make a small change in your managed object model.

### Entity

`Users`

### Attributes

`user_id`

`name`

---

### Entity

`Comments`

### Attributes

`comment_id`

`comment`

### Relationships

#### Relationship - - -  Desination - - -       Inverse

`user`        - - -       `Users` - - -          `NO Inverse`

---

Now , whenever you enter the data for `Comments` object, associate a user relationship with it as

```
 comment.user=theUser
```

where `theUser` is a 'Users' object which you can get from 'Users' table by comparing `user_id`, for that you can use a simple method as by calling the following method for the `userID` that you got from comment data

```
theUser= [self isUserAlreadyExistsWithUserID:userID];
```

where the method definition could be like in `Users` NSManagedObject subclass

```
  +(NSManagedObject*)isUserAlreadyExistsWithUserID uniqueValue:   (id)uniqueValue
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context=[self managedObjectContext];
    NSError*error=nil;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@",uniqueValue];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if(objects && objects.count>0)
    {
        return [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
   {
       return nil;
   }
}
```

---

Now, to fetch comments for particular user in comments NSManagedObject subClass:

```
 +(NSFetchedResultsController*)getCommentsForUser:(Users*)user
  {
    NSString* cacheName=@"Root";

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:cacheName];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context=[self managedObjectContext];


    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class])   inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
     NSPredicate* predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user=%@",user];
    fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

     NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =   [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context   sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:cacheName];
     return theFetchedResultsController;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need this query:

```
SELECT Users.*,Comments.comment_id,Comments.comment FROM Users LEFT JOIN Comments ON Users.user_id = Comments.user_id;
```

This will return list of all users along with their comments. You can modify it, as per your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CoreData? if yes then use try the following code:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Comments",nil]];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];

NSArray* returnArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if([returnArray count] > 0)
{
    Users* user = [returnArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", user.user_id, user.name, user.userComments.comment);
}
```

Also, CoreData uses relationships instead of foreignKeys. Therefore, to get this working you need to setup an inverse relationship `userComments` (many to one) from `Comments` to `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use `NSPredicate` when making a query. You can simply write a `JOIN` query. As [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html) also states that the NSPredicate class is used to define logical conditions used to constrain a search either for a fetch or for in-memory filtering. Also it will be easier to use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html). Here is a [good explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821911/iphone-nspredicate-how-to-do-an-inner-join) to how it can be used. Lets assume you have `NSSet` of `Comments`. You can do something like :

```
[Comments valueForKeyPath:@"users.user_id"];
```

But, if you really want to use `NSPredicate` following is the possible way:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Users"];
    NSError *error;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(user_id == %@)",Comments.user_id];
    [fetchReq setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&error];
```