# joins in coredata using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

How to make **inner joins,outer joins(left,right,full**) in core-data.
I have done it easily in sqlite db using sqlite c based APIs But I couldn't find any resources on how to do it using core-data in Objective C.

Basically I have a need to query CoreData that involves *relation between more than three tables or objects.*

*Note:*

How to set relationship between tables in core-data would be helpful.
such as *Primary key - foreign key relationship,cascade relationship*.

Comment: Core Data is NOT A DATABASE. Stop trying to treat it like a data base. It is an object persistence framework. You really should be starting with a tutorial or something. The whole concept of joins and foreign keys does not belong in core data.

Comment: It also helps to stop thinking of your models as living in tables with joins. Think of them as Entities with Relationships.

Comment: so how can easily query data that involves more than one entities with relationships between them... hope you guys understand my doubt

Comment: like c# has LINQ for its entity framework ORM..

Comment: You create the relationships in your entity model and use those relationships to access related objects. You can use predicates to filter the objects that you are searching for

Comment: see this for more info: vhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821911/iphone-nspredicate-how-to-do-an-inner-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query Core Data you need to create NSPredicates for that and its clearly stated in documentation that you cannot convert any arbitrary  query into NSPredicates.

For more info read this :-https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html

[image]

Comment: can you give me example using NSpredicate how to query data that involves more than two objects and if possible on how to achieve the joins I have mentioned above ...i would appreciate for sure.

Comment: is it possible that I can query using coredata with sql statements

Comment: NO you can't use sql  with core data. In core data try to learn relationships which are way better to use instead of join.

Comment: Can you give me a sample on how to achieve joins using NSPredicate (2 tables,3 tables)