# core data , How to use inner join in core data

Tags: ios, core-data, inner-join

I have two tables. One is `companydetail` and the second is `favCompany` Both have a common `companyID`. How do I get all `companydetail` where `companyID` is inserted in `favCompany`? Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray *)getAll_FavCompany
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * userinfo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"user_info"];

        NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setParentContext:[TDODataManager sharedManager].managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObjectContext *mainManagedObjectContext = [managedObjectContext parentContext];

        NSFetchRequest *fetch_company = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Tbl_companyFav"];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"companyid = %@ AND loginuserid = %@", [userinfo objectForKey:@"user_id"]];
        [fetch_company setPredicate:predicate];


        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *result = [mainManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch_company error:&error];
        return result;

    }
```

I think I need to use `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` like in my code above, but I'm not certain.

Comment: See the linked question, but if you are thinking in terms of "tables" and "joins" and "selects," then you're misunderstanding Core Data. It is not a database. It is an object persistence engine. You should think of it the same way you think of having a bunch of objects in memory that all point to each other. It can just handle object graphs that are much larger than memory would allow. Some problems lend themselves to object persistence. Some lend themselves better to databases. Just don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform join operation like sql in coreData you have to use NSPredicate.

check this link:
[joins in coredata using Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932521/joins-in-coredata-using-objective-c)

It may help you.

Comment: I can't able to understand .

Comment: have you checked that link?